# Send Mail Automatically in Oracle apex in Oracle APEX With report

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

Hey Guys I need Help How to send EMAIL Automatically in oracle APEX, I know some using DBMS_SCHEDULER we can achieve it, I have no idea how to do it where to start any suggestion, Along with that i want to attach a report. COuld you help me?

Can you Suggestest any blog?

Thank You in Advance.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog is a good place to start: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/creating-email-campaign-app-with-oracle-apex

Answer (score 0):

The code below as long as the owner of the job is a schema that has been provisioned for the APEX workspace, or the schema has been granted the role `APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE`. You will need to substitute `100` for your actual application number and `1` with an actual page in that application. The third parameter is the username and can be anything.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_mail_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    apex_session.create_session (100, 1, 'send_email');
    l_mail_id :=
        apex_mail.send (p_to          => 'youremail@gmail.com',
                        p_from        => 'nobody@test.com',
                        p_body        => 'plaintext body',
                        p_body_html   => '<h1>HTML Body</h1>',
                        p_subj        => 'Test Email Subject');
    apex_mail.add_attachment (p_mail_id      => l_mail_id,
                              p_attachment   => EMPTY_BLOB (),
                              p_filename     => 'attachment_name.json',
                              p_mime_type    => 'application/json');
    apex_mail.push_queue;
    apex_session.delete_session;
END;
/
```